# Prevent downtime with one pod replica only

Tags: kubernetes

I have quite heavy pod in terms of resources it uses in my development k8s cluster. Because I don’t want to use more resources for another replica (it is development environment after all and I don’t want to generate too much costs) I want only one replica. But it would be great on the other hand to avoid downtime in scenerio like this: pod is evicted from a node to another node and Kubernetes does not do it with rolling update strategy.

Can podDisruptionBudget be used to force rolling update in case of pods eviction even if there is only one replica? If not, how this can be solved? Is there a way to solve it in Kubernetes with one replica only?

Comment: Estimate how much this pod costs per month, then compare that against how much time and energy you're sinking into solving a problem that can be easily solved by having a second replica.

Comment: I don't think that "preventing downtime" is possible with only one replica. If you only have one replica and that dies, your cluster will still need to notice that, schedule the pod on another node, possibly mount volumes, run any init-containers, then run the normal container. How fast this goes is up to your application, but it won't be 0 downtime.

Comment: If you mean to completely prevent downtime, and you want to minimise resource usage, then you have conflicting goals and you can't satisfy both. For HA (which is what you're describing) the solution is redundancy (resource usage). For lower resources the solution is scarcity. Pick one, you can't have both.

Comment: Maybe not completely prevent downtime, but to prevent it in eviction scenario